# Do I need a lock when using python multi-thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

Think about this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from threading import Thread

count = 0

def test():
    global count
    for i in range(10):
        count = count + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1000):
        Thread(target = test).start()
    print count
```

I use multiple threads, but the result is always correct. Does that mean I could use python threads without a lock when implementing something like a visitor counter ?

Comment: I am not sure, actually, but you should try it with much larger numbers.

Comment: You are right, i use 100000 threads and it fails.

Comment: You can use Queue be cause it's most simplest way to work with native python's threads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need one. Although multithreading works differently in Python, due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), operations that are not atomic in Python-bytecode will still need locking.

In you case, you can inspect the bytecode for your function `test` (`dis.dis(test)`):

```
 3           0 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 33)
             3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
             6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1000)
             9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            12 GET_ITER
       >>   13 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
            16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 4          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (count)   # start of increment
            22 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
            25 BINARY_ADD
            26 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (count)   # end of increment
            29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
       >>   32 POP_BLOCK
       >>   33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            36 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the increment is a 2xload, update, store on bytecode-level, so this wont work. The increment is actually 4 separate operations, which you must protect to ensure they are not interrupted.

In your example the problem remains even if you use `count += 1`, as the bytecode shows:

```
4          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (count)
           22 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
           25 INPLACE_ADD
           26 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need a lock if you just did assignments.

But as you do `count = count + 1`, something can happen between each of reading out `count`, adding `1` and writing to `count`.

Even using `count += 1` wouldn't solve this problem, as this involves an assignment as well. (As the inplace operations involve an assignment under the hood as well, the situation is the same.)

Comment: count += 1 is just a syntatic sugar for count = count + 1

Comment: So, just imagine situation when one thread starts reading value of count for increment it but another thread is incrementing it right now, and first thread write same number what and another, this is a race condition problem.

Comment: @crow16384 In general, your statement is wrong: try it on a list and you see the difference. In the bytecode, it uses `INPLACE_ADD` instead of `BINARY_ADD`. It is the same on ints, however, so for ints and other immutable objects, you are right, as with a missing `.__iadd__()`, the call resorts to `.__add__()`.

Comment: Agree. In generally my statement about **count += 1** is equal to **count = count+1** is wrong, but here was a talk about integers.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you should use Lock. You have got a correct answer in such simple case. Try to make it for range(100000) in **main**. You will see the problem. In my machine the result is 999960, but it is random result. Errors will arise depending on system load and so on.